# How to expire redis key-value 24 hours after pushing?

Tags: python, redis

So I'm using redis to store a list and I need it to expire after 24 hrs, how do I do this?

I tried using expire command but I am able to input only seconds after... what if I want to it to expire on a specific date?
I currently have:

r.rpush(r_id,d_id,l_id,ib_st)
r.expire(resident_id, 10)

Comment: you can enter 24hrs as 86400 seconds. what do you want specifically?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment, you can convert 24 hours to seconds, which is `24 * 60 * 60 = 86400` and use the `EXPIRE` command:

```
r.expire(resident_id, 86400)
```

Alternatively, to set expiration to a specific date, you can use the [EXPIREAT](https://redis.io/commands/expireat/) command which accepts absolute time in the form of [unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).
For example, if you use `redis-py` client, [expireat()](https://redis-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/commands.html#redis.commands.core.CoreCommands.expireat)'s second parameter is either an int (unix time) or datetime, so you can set the expiration to, e.g., 2023/2/2 10:0:0 by doing:

```
d = datetime.datetime(2023, 2, 2, 10)
r.expireat("a", resident_id)
```